# Disqus Integration with my authentication system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, comments, disqus

Is it possible to integrate Disqus with my existing authentication solution?

I am developing a app using RoR and authologic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disqus offers a VIP service aimed at organisations with a reasonable budget.

I spoke with them last week and they told me they are planning on rolling out a self-serve integration option later this year. It will be cheaper than their VIP offering.

As a (very limited) stop gap, you could pre-fill the username and email address on the default 'Guest' tab with the data gathered from authlogic using Javascript. To my knowledge this is as far as you can integrate Disqus right now.

[@bkno](http://twitter.com/bkno)

Comment: This was helpful, however - is there any way to prevent the popup with pre-filled fields from appearing? I tried disqus_skip_auth=true; but without success.

Comment: Probably simplest to add display:none around the fields you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus has added in a 'Professional' version which is 'only' $299 per month and supports single sign on. That said, $3600 a year for this feature is crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign-On (SSO) is free add-on now. Read
https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-integrating-single-sign-on